Connecting nodejs applicaktion with HIK vision Access control
I have a HIK vision access controll device and i have used ISAPI and postman gives me the data fine but using node i am not able to make request using digest authorization and the error saying failed authorization persist.
const axios = require('axios');
const AxiosDigestAuth = require('@mhoc/axios-digest-auth').default;

// Replace these with your actual username and password
const username = 'admin';
const password = 'Ultimate@22';

const digestAuth = new AxiosDigestAuth({
  username: username,
  password: password,
});

let config = {
  method: 'post',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'http://192.168.1.113/ISAPI/ContentMgmt/logSearch?format=json',
  headers: { }
};

digestAuth.request(config)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });


and the error is
response: {
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: {
      date: 'Thu, 06 Jun 2024 18:55:40 GMT',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
      'content-length': '145',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=98',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },

